# Deep links and Outlook safe links protection

Tags: outlook, ios-universal-links, safelinks

I have deep links configured on iOS and Android using universal links. They're working fine. If the app isn't installed, the request goes through the web site, which I currently have an apache Rewrite redirecting them to the home page of the web site with links to install the app.

Emails that go through Outlook safe links protection, a feature of Office 365 subscriptions, rewrites all URLs in your received emails. So my deep link universal link is rewritten to an outlook handling URL (na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com), so iOS nor Android have the chance to handle it immediately. This redirects to the original url, however Safari then doesn't treat is as a universal link, at least not in the way I have it configured and the user then gets redirected to the home page, and the app never opens.

I can't be the only one facing this issue, as there are a lot of hotmail users out there.

Anyone got any suggestions on how to alleviate this issue and make universal links work with outlook safe links protection?

Note that this issue only is affecting iOS 13 and Android. It works ok on iOS 14.

I know it's possible, as we've got emails from other apps that seem to be successfully doing it, albeit via a lot of link forwarding it seems.

Comment: I also am having this issue. iOS users using the Outlook app are unable to open my app deeplinks.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this issue? also facing it.